# sliding a div over another for ipad

Tags: jquery

this is sliding one div over another on MouseOver and back on MouseOut. Now, on the ipad when I touch the maindiv it slides the lowerdiv but I cannot figure it out to make it slide back to show the maindiv again on 'touch' again. I also tried jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js but there is no reaction. i want it to slide back onclick or touch and if not touched after set time X. Can someone help please?

```
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        $(function(){
            $(".maindiv").hover(function(){
                $(this).children('.lowerdiv').stop().animate({top:0})
            },function() {
                    $(this).children('.lowerdiv').stop().animate({top:140})
                })

        })

    //-->
    </script>

    <style>
        .maindiv{
            height:66px;
            width:390px;
            background:#FFF;
            position:relative;
            overflow:hidden;
            float:left;
            margin:0px;
        }
        .lowerdiv{
        height:66px;
            width:390px;
            background:#FFF;
            position:absolute;
            top:140px;
    }
        </style>

     <div class="maindiv">
        //Main div content
        <div class="lowerdiv">
            //2. div content
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this could help you: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/fast-touch-event-handling-eliminate-click-delay.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

i hope it will solve hover problem in touch devices :) (i have tested it on my tablet, after lifting up finger/touch, lower div is slide back)

No need of use timer or detecting second touch after some delay i suggest.

**UPDATED:**

```
var $mainDiv = $(".maindiv"),
    $lowerDiv = $mainDiv.children('.lowerdiv'); 

function showHideChild(flag){

    var temp = (flag)? 0 : 140;     
    $lowerDiv.stop().animate({top:temp});
}

$mainDiv.on({
    mouseover: function(){                  
        showHideChild(true);
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        showHideChild(false);
    },   
    touchstart: function(){
        showHideChild(true);
    },
    touchend: function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
           showHideChild(false);
        },1500);
    }
});
```

working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/QwvtL/3/

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, it is working as you said. the only problem is that when i touch for the time being then ipad marks it to copy so this is not an option. i need to tap once to make 2. div appear and touch again to make it disappear and or making it disappear via setTimeout.

Comment: check above fiddle link in your tablet/ipad